# Saving excel web page to web server without disclosing UNC

Tags: excel, web, unc

My website users have dashboard containing all the graphs, tables etc. created in excel and now they wish to publish it online.The **intranet web server** is in LAN connection with client PCs and generally website is accessed something like this:

*http:\\10.222.12.52:8080\mywebsite\index.html*

Now they are saving the excel sheet **with AUTO PUBLISH OPTION ON** as a web page (say dashboard.htm) and they wish to view updated dashboard using URL like

*http:\\10.222.12.52:8080\mywebsite\dashboard.htm*

The problem is while saving excel as web page, we need to enter entire **UNC path** to website folder i.e. *\\10.222.12.52\c$\Apache24\htdocs\mywebsite\dashboard.htm* and the same should not be disclosed as almost any user in team (not necessary just admin) would be handed in-charge to save new dashboards quarterly.

Is there anything that can be done as an **alternative to UNC path?** something like 
*\\10.222.12.52\mywebsite\dashboard.htm* that would be accepted by excel's "save as" dialog box to save the excel as web page..

Comment: Security by obscurity is no security at all. What about FTP? Or share just the folder where the files go to an appropriate set of users?

Comment: STO I agree. regarding FTP I came across this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/put-excel-data-on-a-web-page-HP005256150.aspx and it says path as drive, folder, web folder, web server or ftp location but no examples are listed! can u give one?

Comment: Excel doesn't support the ability to save to a url directly. You either need to integrate with Sharepoint/WebDAV/similar which Excel _can_ save to or your users will need to upload the file using the standard file upload form that we all know and love...